# Screen schemes necessary for transition screen or not?

Tags: screen, jira, transition, administration

I've created a project, several type issues, screen, fields and associated schemes. After I have realized a worflow, a notification and a permission scheme to manage the different roles.

As every screen require a screen scheme, I wonder if it was necessary for me to create some screen schemes especially for the screens which appear during transition ... because, I discover that my workflow, shared by a lot of issue types works only with my first issue type, but not the followings (for my first issue type, the screen transition appears correctly with its fields -- for the other, these one only let appear a comment field, instead of transition screen fields like my first issue type)

Are screen schemes necessary for the transition screen inside a workflow or not ? do I forget anything for these one ?

Any help appreciated,

Best regards

Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition screens do not need to belong to a screen scheme to be used inside a workflow. Just assign the screen to the appropriate transition and you will be good to go. You should look over your Workflow and make sure you have the screen in the correct Transitions

Comment: So, the answer is: no